# how to write code for multiple instances of console application in .net

Tags: .net, console-application

I have a console application in c#, which will import data from csv file to table storage. I want to spin up multiple instances of the console, but I am not sure how to do this. my requirement is the exe should open multiple instances and process files simultaneously. I got the idea by reading http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/12/working-with-154-million-records-on.html , but I got struck up that how to spin up multiple instances of console.

Comment: Do you really need multiple instances of the application? I would bet for multiple thread instead that would do the job in a single application instance. Would this not be sufficient?

Comment: Can you give details of what you've tried so far?